# How to automatically pull data from access into excel using a python script

Tags: python, excel, ms-access, odbc

I am looking to **automatically** pull data from Access to Excel using a python script. Manually, I have to do the following inside Excel:

1. Click on "Data"--> "from Access".
   [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCW3n.png)
2. Select the Data Source (.accdb)
   [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K68E.png)
3. Input the credentials for Oracle ODBC Driver Connect [Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIMFa.png)

This fairly easy process inside Excel I would like to automate using a python script. Could you get me an idea how this could be achieved? Could I possibly run a macro from python that does these 3 steps ?

Thanks for your help!

Greetings,

Daniel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy data from MS Access to MS Excel using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630142/copy-data-from-ms-access-to-ms-excel-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two parts:

1. Reading an access database; to do so you can use [`pyodbc`](https://datatofish.com/how-to-connect-python-to-ms-access-database-using-pyodbc/) to read an access database and run query on it. e.g.:

   ```py
   import pyodbc

   conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=path where you stored the Access file\file name.accdb;')
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute('select * from table name')

   for row in cursor.fetchall():
       print (row)
   ```
2. Write your data to Excel file; for this you can use [`XlsxWriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/getting_started.html) to write excel files:

   ```py
   import xlsxwriter

   workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
   worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

   worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')

   workbook.close()
   ```